# iOS UITests can't do basics actions after Swift 3 update

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode-ui-testing

In my iOS i'm implementing UITests using `XCUITest`. It worked great since I had Swift 2.3, but after updating the app to Swift 3 basic actions like `tap()` don't work anymore.

Just a simple code that doesn't work anymore:

```
XCUIApplication().buttons["orgMenu"].tap()
```

throws

```
Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=9 "Error -25204 getting snapshot for element <AXUIElement 0x7f8297d15a50> {pid=32375}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error -25204 getting snapshot for element <AXUIElement 0x7f8297d15a50> {pid=32375}}
```

The name of the button is correct: if I record the test and tap the button the line above is exactly what I get.

The button is in the view since I'm waiting for the existence of it (tried both manually, through a breakpoint, and programmatically with this:

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: XCUIApplication().buttons["orgMenu"], handler: nil
waitForExpectations(timeout: time, handler: nil)
```

)

And anyway, it worked before Swift 3.
Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tap on the button in the simulator manually with the same build without the app crashing?

Comment: @Oletha, yes I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just answer to my own question, since I found a workaround.

Since Swift3, for some reason, UI tests are not able to manage views with a `loadMore` pattern. If I have in my view a `TableView` and somewhere in the code a manage the `loadMore` pattern manually, and in a test I tap a button, the loadMore is called in a sort of infinite loop, and that overheads the app's resources, making the test fail.

Workaround: just deactivate any `loadMore` if a UI Test is running.

In the tests' setup:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    continueAfterFailure = false
    app.launchEnvironment = ["isUITest":"YES"]
    app.launch()
}
```

In the view with the loadData:

```
-(void)loadMore
{
    if ([Utils isRunningUITest]) {
        return;
    }
    // My actual function.
}
```

and my Utils

```
+(BOOL)isRunningUITest {
    NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
    return environment[@"isUITest"];
}
```

Sorry for Swift and Objective-C mix, hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: NSProcessInfo’s environment property is read-only.  This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do something like:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
XCTAssert(app.buttons["orgMenu"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10))
app.buttons["orgMenu"].tap()
```